# Question about exercise 21.10 in The TeXbook

Tags: tex-core, expansion, texbook.tex

This exercise asks how to store expansion of `\chapno` at the moment when `\write` is processed, but `\the\count0` must be expanded at the moment of `\shipout`. Here is a full example:

```
\def\chapno{5}
\newwrite\cont \openout\cont=out.txt
\edef\next{\write\cont{\chapno,\noexpand\the\count0}}\next
\def\chapno{6}
\count0=100
\bye
```

A curious technique is used in the answer:

```
{\let\the=0\edef\next{\write\cont{<token list>}}\next}
```

Is using `\noexpand` equivalent to the `\let`-trick? And why `\noexpand` is not used in the answer - just to show the possibilities?

Comment: It's not the same.  `\noexpand\the` actually expands to `\the`, whereas by using `\let\the=0` you make `\the` an unexpandable token.

Comment: @HenriMenke will the token list in `\write` after both methods be the same? (in all possible cases - not just in this example)

Comment: In this case the token lists will be the same, but the `\let\the=0` makes *all* `\the` tokens inside the group unexpandable, whereas `\noexpand` can be applied selectively.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is essentially how the latex `\protected@write` works as well:

```
\long\def \protected@write#1#2#3{%
      \begingroup
       \let\thepage\relax
       #2%
       \let\protect\@unexpandable@protect
       \edef\reserved@a{\write#1{#3}}%
       \reserved@a
      \endgroup
      \if@nobreak\ifvmode\nobreak\fi\fi
}
```

Typically in such a construct you can use `\noexpand` in front of tokens that you have control of while writing the macro but the `<token list>` in your example will usually come as `#1` from some section title argument in the document, but you want to suppress the expansions of all registers until `\shipout` and the text may refer to any of them.
so making `\the` non expandable (it doesn't matter much what you `\let`  it to, `0` or `\relax` or any other non expandable token then it will stay as itself in the `\edef` but have its normal expandable definition in the `\write`.

Note the exercise has the easy case where the chapter number is an expandable macro. In most formats chapters would be automatically numbered so using a count register and also perhaps ultimately accessed by `\the` in which case suppressing all `\the` expansion might be too much. (Note LaTeX just suppresses `\thepage` letting other counters expand at the point of use, not the final shipout).